# Unable to upload a large attachment with MS Graph API

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi, microsoft-graph-mail

I'm trying to add a large attachment to an email using the Microsoft Graph API.  The documentation is not totally clear on what the actual capability of the non-beta version of the graph api is, but this is what I've tried so far.
(in all of these examples 'this.client' is an instance of the Microsoft Auth Provider, authenticated against the MS graph api)

1. Use LargeFileUploadTask to create an upload session.

```js
    const uploadSession = await LargeFileUploadTask.createUploadSession(
        this.client,
        `/me/messages/${draftId}/attachments/createUploadSession`,
        {
          AttachmentItem: {
            '@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior': 'fail',
            name: file.name,
            attachmentType: 'file',
            size: file.size,
          },
        }
      );

    const uploadTask = await new LargeFileUploadTask(this.client, fileObject, uploadSession);

    await uploadTask.upload();
```

The problem with this approach is that even though the LargeFileUploadTask class comes directly from the `@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client` package, the response url is for the old outlook REST api, not the graph api.  Since I don't have a token for the REST api the request fails with the message "The audience claim value is invalid 'aud'".

1a. I tried hand rolling this as well, without using the LargeFileUploadTask class and ran into the same problem.  The url returned for subsequent PUT requests is for the old outlook REST api.

```js
      const payload = {
        AttachmentItem: {
          attachmentType: 'file',
          name: file.name,
          size: file.size,
        },
      };

      const uploadSession = await this.client
        .api(`/me/messages/${draftId}/attachments/createUploadSession`)
        .post(payload);

    // uploadSession.url is still outlook.com, not graph.microsoft.com
```

2. Use oneDriveLargeFileUploadTask to upload the file to OneDrive, then create a referenceAttachment on the draft.

```js
    const options = {
      fileName: file.name,
      rangeSize: 1024 * 1024,
    };

    const uploadTask = await OneDriveLargeFileUploadTask.create(client, file, options);
    const attachment = await uploadTask.upload();

    await this.client.api(`/me/messages/${draftId}/attachments`).post(attachment);
```

The file uploads to OneDrive successfully, but I get the following error for POST request to the /attachments endpoint (the last line of the snippet).

`"The property 'SourceUrl' is required when creating the entity."`

As far as I can tell sourceUrl is only supported by the beta graph api, which I'm not using.

Is there any way to achieve this functionality with the Microsoft Graph API?

Comment: The URL that is created for the upload session doesn't requires any authentication eg in the documentation it states "Including the Authorization header when issuing the PUT call may result in a HTTP 401 Unauthorized response. The Authorization header and bearer token should only be sent when issuing the POST during the first step. It should be not be included when issuing the PUT"

Comment: @GlenScales, thank you so much, I don't know whether your comment solved OP's problem, but id did solve mine.